# RecyclerView и SetTeg

Tags: android, recyclerview

У меня есть 2 класса , MainActivity и RecyclerAdapter
В MainActivity есть выплывающий диалог:

```
public void DialogClick(View view) {
        Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(view.getTag()));
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle((CharSequence) mDataSet.get(1))
                .setMessage((CharSequence) mDataSet1.get(1))

                .setCancelable(false)
                .setNegativeButton("закрыть",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
```

В котором я хочу , что бы появлялась информация из базы данных. Но что бы понять, на какой элемент RecyclerView была нажата кнопка, нужно как я понял, использовать SetTeg и GetTeg. Но он выдает Null.
Вот RecyclerAdapter:

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                     int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.recycler_item, parent, false);

    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    v.setTeg(vh);
    return vh;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тег тут вообще не нужен. В адаптере вам надо в onBindViewHolder повесить слушатель нажатий и в нём показать диалог, коий будет брать данные для отображения из списка данных, отображаемых адаптером. Т.к. в onBindViewHolder есть аргумент `position` то вы точно будете знать какой именно элемент списка отобразить в диалоге.